# Web Api 2 receive json array

Tags: c#, angularjs, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api2

model

```
public class modelVenta {
    public int idvendedor { get; set; }
    public int idcliente { get; set; }
    public int idproducto { get; set; }
    public int cantidad { get; set; }
    public decimal precio { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
}

public class modelVentas {
    public List<string> modeloVenta { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/ventas/Add")]
public HttpResponseMessage putVentas( List<modelVentas> data)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

JSON

```
var data = [{
        "idvendedor": 1,
        "idcliente": 1,
        "idproducto": 1,
        "cantidad": 2,
        "precio": 12.0,
        "fecha": 1476445327124
    }, {
        "idvendedor": 1,
        "idcliente": 1,
        "idproducto": 2,
        "cantidad": 4,
        "precio": 23.0,
        "fecha": 1476445327124
    }, {
        "idvendedor": 1,
        "idcliente": 1,
        "idproducto": 1,
        "cantidad": 4,
        "precio": 35.0,
        "fecha": 1476445327124
    }];
```

Send data

```
$http.put("http://localhost:54233/api/ventas/Add", JSON.stringify({
        modeloVenta: data
    })).then(function () {
        toastr.info('Elemento insertado correctamente');
    });
```

I validate the Json in http://jsonlint.com/ and is ok, but every time I send from AngularJS, api controller web, always receives Null.
please community, someone could help me solve this problem?

Comment: Your `putVentas` method doesn't seem to be doing anything, but returning a HTTP 200 status code? Or is that just for testing? Could you clarify - are you saying that the `List<modelVentas> data` argument is `null` and you're wondering why?

Comment: Looks like you're sending a list, but receiving a list of list, perhaps that's your issue.

Comment: I agree with @OmriAharon - The type you're receiving in your API is a `List<List<string>>`. Doesn't this need to be a `List<modelVenta>` instead?

Comment: return HTTP 200 status code is a dummy, but when I make a debug on the controller, data is always null

Comment: Try replacing `List<modelVentas> data` with `List<modelVenta> data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `putVentas()` method is expecting a `List<modelVentas>` - With a `modelVentas` simply having a property of `List<string>`.

Your JSON that you're sending is actually a `List<modelVenta>`, which the DefaultModelBinder will try and deserialize to the type you've specified in the signature, from the JSON data it receives.

This is why `data` is `null`, as it doesn't translate to the type the method signature is expecting.

---

Your JSON is trying to pass a list of `modelVenta` to the method.

To fix this, you will need to update the API method to match the type that JSON is sending. Change your signature of the API method to be:

```
public HttpResponseMessage putVentas(List<modelVenta> data)
{
    // do something with the data

    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

And your DefaultModelBinder should pick up that you're passing a `List<modelVenta>` instead.

Comment: thanks @djgeoffjames for the fix sent, the controller operates correctly

Comment: No problem @GabrielSule -- Glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote the answer if it is useful; and if it is the solution you used, to mark is as accepted answer when possible. Happy coding! :)